# How can I load a json model on serverside?

Tags: three.js

How can I load a json model on serverside? When I use ObjectLoader to parse json, it give me a prompt message as following.

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at ObjectLoader.parseGeometries (\node_modules\three\build\three.js:39019:24)
    at ObjectLoader.parse (\node_modules\three\build\three.js:38716:26)
```